# repeating function in dynamic tables

Tags: jquery

i have dynamically generated tables .there are some input fields in foot section when u add some values in input field it saves values in the body of that table in the form of rows .
here is my code

```
 <table border="1" class="entity_table">
   <tfoot>
     <tr>
       <td>
        <div class="pane1"></div>
        <div class="pane2">
          <input type="text" id="name"><br>
          <select id="data">
           <option value="1">int</option>
           <option value="2">tinyint</option>
         </select>
         <br><span id="save">save</span>
       </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </tfoot>
 <tbody class="table-body" id='myid'></tbody>
</table>
```

and here is my JS code to save the values of input field in its parent table

```
   $(function(){
     $('#save').click(function(){
     var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').val();
     var data =  $(this).closest('tr').find('select').val();                 
    $(this).closest('table').find('tbody').append('<tr><td>'+name+' and '+data+'</td></tr>');
   }); 
  });
```

its working fine saving values in its parent table .but when i start generating more dynamic tabled the first tables start to repeat the values, it add two rows with same data instead of one ..seems like its calling the save function twice .and trice if there are three tables and 4 times for four tables .

can anyone help please why is it so ...any help how should i solve this ???

thanx

Comment: You shouldn't add more than one element with the same id within your document.

Comment: how are you generating the tables? save is working fine. show a demo (jsfiddle) of what's the issue.

Comment: first of all you're using `id` in that table so in case if you're cloning it, there'll be multiple elements with same id making your document invalid, secondly, you're not delegating you're event handler so it won't probably work in a dynamically generated table, unless you're binding it after generation of table. finally, unless you share the whole code including that generates the tables, we can't find the issue.